# LOAD simple CSV file MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

Trying to load a .csv this simple:

```
"Id";"Values"
"1";"Value1"
"2";"Value2"
...
...
"n";"Valuen"
```

Into a table with 2 fields

```
id       int(11) primary
values   varchar(255)
```

like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_name.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ';'
    ENCLOSED BY '"'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

but when i load it, I get something like

```
+----+--------------+
| id | value        | 
+----+--------------+
|  1 | value1" "2   | 
|  2 | value3" "4   |
|  3 | value5" "6   |
|  4 | value7" "8   |
|  5 | value9" "10  | 
|  6 | value11" "12 | 
+----+--------------+
```

as if it didn't understand the linebreak rule \n

pulling my hair off already. what am I doind wrong?

in other words, what is the correct query for loading this file?

Comment: Do you have access to a hex editor? Make sure that the line break is just `\n` and there aren't some other non-printable characters in there.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski thanks for the hex editor tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one-

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file_name.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE tbl_name FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\' TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```